# Return the most popular day for bookings

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to write a MySQL query that returns the most popular day of the week for bookings to take place.

I am unsure of my issue here. MySQL returned an error saying there is a syntax error, but because of the complexity of the query (for me anyway) I am unable to see the cause.

Error reads:

> "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''tbl_booking' GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT('tbl_booking.booking_date',
>   '%W') ORDER BY ' at line 2"

```
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT('tbl_booking.booking_date', '%W'), COUNT(DATE_FORMAT('tbl_booking.booking_date', '%W')) AS 'mostpopularday'
FROM 'tbl_booking'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT('tbl_booking.booking_date', '%W')
ORDER BY 'mostpopularday' DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I have used the DATE_FORMAT() function previously, but never for sorting data. I am quite new to MySQL/PhpMyAdmin, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure about usage of `'` around table/column names?

Comment: Good work with your first question! Hope to see more from you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-back-ticks-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your query looks ok, but you have syntax errors. You shouldn't be using `'` for column and table names. In mysql you can use  `` ` `` for quoting tablenames and column names

```
SELECT 
  DATE_FORMAT(tbl_booking.booking_date, '%W'), 
  COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(tbl_booking.booking_date, '%W')) AS mostpopularday
FROM tbl_booking
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tbl_booking.booking_date, '%W')
ORDER BY mostpopularday DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you! You're correct, there was no need for the quotations. Query works as intended now.

Comment: you are welcome! if this answer is helpful for you, please consider to up-vote and/or mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your `'` delimiters around your table and column names are incorrect.

For best results get rid of the delimiters altogether, like this.

```
 SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tbl_booking.booking_date, '%W'), 
        COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(tbl_booking.booking_date, '%W')) AS mostpopularday
   FROM tbl_booking
  GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tbl_booking.booking_date, '%W')
  ORDER BY mostpopularday DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

If you must keep them, they should look like this. Notice the backticks:  `` ` ``.

```
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`tbl_booking`.`booking_date`, '%W'), 
          COUNT(DATE_FORMAT(`tbl_booking`.`booking_date`, '%W')) AS mostpopularday
     FROM `tbl_booking`
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`tbl_booking`.`booking_date`, '%W')
    ORDER BY mostpopularday DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you! The first one works perfectly, as intended.